# asp.net send mail

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

i am writing a program to send mail using asp.net, it gives me an error as the "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid. Here is my code

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.To = "msangita@abc.co.in";
    msg.From = "msangita@abc.co.in";
    msg.Subject = "hello";
    SmtpMail.Send(msg);
}
```

Comment: You have asked 9 questions and still ahvent learnt how to use the "code" option?

Comment: Just noticed your email ID in the code. Please replace or remove it.

Comment: I think you've just signed up for a bucket load of spam by posting your email address sangita :)

Comment: You have asked 9 questions and still ahvent learnt how to use the "accept answer" button?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the SMTP server you want to use, something like

```
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mail.provider.com";
```

<sub>Perhaps you might want to take a look at the System.Net.Mail, which is the new mail class in .Net 2, System.Web.Mail is obsolete.</sub>

Comment: Not if the SMTP server is local, anyway +1, because that's the common reason.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this exception has to deal with the following line of code (or I should say ABSENCE of the following line of code):

```
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mail.your-domain.com"
```

By default, if SmtpMail.SmtpServer is not set, System.Web.Mail is supposed to use localhost as the default property. However, for some reason this doesn't appear work.

You could have done a simple google search for this ;-)

[Source](http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/4.2.2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One additional comment: I found that on Server 2008, your website needs to run in an application pool with identity other than ApplicationPoolIdentity (the default) for e-mail to be sent via localhost (i.e., no SmtpMail.SmtpServer set).  All of the other identities work (NetworkService, LocalService, LocalSystem), just not ApplicationPoolIdentity.

If you specify SmtpMail.SmtpServer as something other than null or localhost, ApplicationPoolIdentity can be used.